# Error when using dllimport in a DLL client

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I'm currently creating a DLL and the client which goes with it using the stored procedure mentioned at a lot of places on the internet. Basically, create a DLL project which actually defines a PROJECT_EXPORTS in the Project.h file.

Something like this:

```
// Assume the name of the project is SanProj and the header file is SanProj.h
#ifdef SANPROJ_EXPORTS
    #define SANPROJ_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define SANPROJ_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Now the normal way of using this header is to include this in all the headers of your API classes and using SANPROJ_EXPORTS for "exporting" declarations when in the DLL and "importing" declarations when used as a client. For e.g. let's say we have a header file with a currency class:

```
// currency.hpp
#include "SanProj.h"
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

namespace SanProj {

    class SANPROJ_API Currency {

    public:
        Currency();
        const std::string& name();
        const std::string& code();
        bool empty() const;

    protected:
        std::string name_;
        std::string code_;
    };

    SANPROJ_API bool operator==(const Currency&,
                    const Currency&);

    SANPROJ_API bool operator!=(const Currency&,
                    const Currency&);

    SANPROJ_API std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Currency& c);
}
```

And another header file with specific currencies:

```
// allccy.hpp
namespace SanProj {

    class SANPROJ_API USDCurrency : public Currency {
    public:
        USDCurrency() {
            name_ = "American Dollar";
            code_ = "USD";
        }
    };


    class SANPROJ_API CADCurrency : public Currency {
    public:
        CADCurrency() {
            name_ = "Canadian Dollar";
            code_ = "CAD";
        }
    };

}
```

The above classes form the contract of the DLL project. Now let's look at the client project files, which is a single class with `main` function:

```
#include "currency.hpp"
#include "allccy.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace SanProj;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    USDCurrency uccy;
    std::cout << uccy;
}
```

Assuming all referencing/settings are already done in the Visual Studio project, I get the following error when trying to compile the client:

```
1>testdll.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall SanProj::USDCurrency::~USDCurrency(void)" (__imp_??1USDCurrency@SanProj@@QAE@XZ)
1>testdll.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall SanProj::USDCurrency::USDCurrency(void)" (__imp_??0USDCurrency@SanProj@@QAE@XZ)
```

Not surprisingly, this error goes away when I remove the `dllimport` part from the `SanProj.h` file and the executable is created.

My question is, what's the point of the IDE generated `dllimport` if we can't compile clients against the header? Is there a way I can continue to use the header with both `dllimport` and `dllexports` and remove the linker errors? Also, why is it trying to resolve the symbol which has `dllimport` from the LIB file?

TIA,
/sasuke

**EDIT:** Linker Command used by VisualStudio; as you can see, it has the LIB file.

> /OUT:"E:\vsprojects\SomeSln\Release\testdll.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO
> /NOLOGO "E:\vsprojects\SomeSln\Release\SanProj.lib" "kernel32.lib"
> "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib"
> "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib"
> "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST
> /ManifestFile:"Release\testdll.exe.intermediate.manifest"
> /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
> /DEBUG /PDB:"E:\vsprojects\SomeSln\Release\testdll.pdb"
> /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF
> /PGD:"E:\vsprojects\SomeSln\Release\testdll.pgd" /LTCG /TLBID:1
> /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

Comment: All you have to do is compile the DLL with `dllexport` and the client with `dllimport` *and provide the right library to the linker*. The error messages suggest that the linker is missing the library, and so can't actually link against the symbols (not a problem with the `import`/`export`).

Comment: It looks like you are not linking your executable to the import library created for your .dll.

Comment: @peachykeen: That's what I'm doing right now. I know the paths/configurations are good enough because removing the `dllimport` from the `SanProj.h` file successfully creates the executable. If it was an issue with linker not able to find the import lib, it should have complained even when I removed the `dllimport`, no?

Comment: @drescherjm: Please read the above comment.

Comment: I do not believe the compiler will automatically add the import library to your link settings for any executable that uses the dll. Its never done that for me in the 15+ years I have written dlls. AN easy way you can add the import library to your link settings for all executables using your dll is using a pragma but I do not see that in your code.

Comment: @sasuke No, when you remove the `dllimport`, it won't look for the import library at all. Turn the build log to detailed or debug and check the linker settings.

Comment: @drescherjm: I guess I was bad with words, I am actually doing all the settings required for setting up the library path. Of course I understand the compiler/IDE won't be automatically able to find the import lib. Please have a look at the updated post at the end, I have added the linker command. It has the import lib.

Comment: @peachykeen: I'm not sure about that. Let me tell you what I have tried: I removed the DLL import statement from the header file *and* removed the import lib setting from the `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` and the project didn't build. I put in the additional dependencies setting back and it started building. This implies that even after removing the `dllimport` the linker for my executable still requires the import lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no solution to this problem. I ended up giving up on using `dllimport` in the client code and take a performance hit. :(

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm also stuck on this one.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Sure I'm wrong as the answer of *jcopenha* is the answer. The linker complains about the missing constructor and destructor that you don't export in the DLL. However the rest is still valid.

[...]

You should have two build targets (or projects, depending on the environment you use).

First target will build the DLL. The files this target will need to be built are, based on what you report:

```
currency.hpp
allccy.hpp
```

and probably the implementation of the base class "currency". You must have defined SANPROJ_EXPORTS in the preprocessor defines in order to use the currency.hpp file as a definition of the functions exported by your DLL.
This target will produce a .DLL file and probably (depends on configuration) a .lib file. It may also generate other files like a text representation of the exports of the library (a .DEF file).

Then, you need to build your application (the second target/project):
the header file you need is just simply the same of the library for the #include part. Just be sure to NOT define SANPROJ_EXPORTS or the compiler will try to export again the simbols instead of importing them.
Then you need to add the following settings to the compiler and linker:

- Add to the include path the directory containing the .hpp header.
- Add to the libraries path of the linker (lib) the directory
  containing the .lib file.
- Tell the linker to also link against the .lib you just created (add the full name of your lib file, assuming the DLL is named "currency" probably it will be "currency.lib".

Where and how to add this settings depends on the toolchain/environment and compiler you are using.

In the end, be sure that the compiled executable will be able to find the DLL in the project folder or in a system directory (in the PATH) or it will not start. Just copy the DLL with a post-build step if you have the executable in a different folder than the one used to build the DLL.

The fact that removing the _dllimport part will build the project is probably due to the compiler finding the header AND the implementation of the functions you meant to export, and building all of them statically into the executable.

Assuming you are not in the .NET "managed world", and that we are talking about Windows, there are some more points to look at if you want to distribute your library, but this is another answer.

Comment: +1; thanks for the breakdown. I'm a bit confused with the 2nd and 3rd steps, aren't they the same? I mean right now I'm using `Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies` to specify the full path of the LIB and it is working out fine.

Comment: Using Visual Studio you can directly specify the file name with the full path in 'Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies'. Otherwise you can simply write only the file name here and use 'Linker -> General -> Additional Libraries Directories'. Visual Studio will search for the library into this directories. If you use multilple configurations (i.e. Debug/Release), you have to set this for each one or work with "All configurations".

Answer (score 2):

It is specifically complaining about the constructor and destructor for the `USDCurrency` class but your code does not show those methods as being adorned with `SANPROJ_API`.

And since you define the `USDCurrency` constructor in the header, when you remove the `dllimport` from the class `USDCurrency` you are getting an implementation defined in your current project and not a reference to the one defined in the DLL.

Comment: AH, that sounds logical; +1. But question: I'm adorning the USDCurrency class with the export in the allccys.hpp file, so why is the error issued for the constructor? Also, given that most classes don't need to specify an explicit destructor, is there a way to get around this issue apart from removing the `dllimport` from the header file?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else has beat this, I will too.

Re the compiler adding libs, the compiler does just that: compiles. The linker links (doh). Your's appears to be a linker configuration issue, and there are a number of ways to solve this.

If you have a multi-project solution file (.sln) that contains both your DLL project and your EXE project, you can establish an explicit dependency by setting the DLL project to be 'referenced' by the EXE project in the EXE project. Within this, make sure the "Link Library Dependencies" is marked 'true'.

The References configuration is actually a .NET addition starting with VS2005, though it still works for standard C/C++ projects as well. You can skip that and configure the import library to link implicitly on the Linker/Input settings of the EXE project. A setting called "Link Library Dependencies" can me marked true there as well. This also requires you configure the solutions project dependencies (Build/Project Dependencies...). In your case you select your EXE project as "depends on.." and check the DLL project. This ensures that your EXE will be relinked whenever your DLL project is rebuilt and a new import library is created.

If requested, screenshots of all of this are available. It gets to be old habit to set it up after a few go-arounds. At this point I'm fairly sure I can do it blind-folded.

Comment: +1; As already noted in my edit and other comments, I was bad with my wording. I actually am adding the library dependencies to Visual Studio and still getting the error. I did it by going to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Library dependencies`. BTW, if you have the screenies handy, I would love to have a look at them and confirm my settings.

Comment: You actually hit it right. If both projects are being built in the same solution you can do it either way I described. Completely getting to basics and just specifying the actual output  imp lib from your DLL on the addn' libs will work as well. But don't forget to set your project build dependencies (i.e., make your EXE dependent on your DLL to ensure a DLL code change will trigger the EXE to relink. I'll try and find a way to put the screenies up somewhere without beating this solution any further.